# When register BroadcastReceiver it returns Intent = null (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm new in this Android, and really stuck with it..

Never that was like that - on a start level and already stuck.

When register the Receiver class it returns Intent = null.. means it doesn't know anything about such request (Action, Intent)..

Tested on Nexus Emulator + Samsung device NOTE4.. same result.

Please, help me. What is a tricky thing I do not see yet?

**General activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EventBroadcaster sms;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent ret;
        sms = new EventBroadcaster();
        sms.setMainActivity(this);
        sms.say("Hello from EventBroadcaster");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        //filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        ret = registerReceiver(sms, filter);
        //******************************************//
        if (ret == null) {
            sms.say("Fault to activate Broadcaster.. Intent = null");
        }
    }

    public void showToast(String message){
        // Show Alert
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class EventBroadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MainActivity ma;
    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity context) {
        ma = context;
        say("MainActivity reference is received");
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        say("Notification received");
    }

    public void say(String phrase){
        ma.showToast(phrase);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

==============================================

So, after Vishnu answered, I think wouldn't be extra to place the working code of the 
**General Activity**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.provider.Telephony;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EventBroadcaster sms;
    final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sms = new EventBroadcaster();
        sms.setMainActivity(this);
        sms.say("Hello from EventBroadcaster");

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS);
    }
    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS);
    } else { /*Permission granted*/ }

    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Intent ret;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                    ret = registerReceiver(sms, filter);
                    if (ret != null) {
                        sms.say("Permission to READ SMS granted");
                    }

                } else {
                    sms.say("Ooops, no permission to READ SMS");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void showToast(String message){
        // Show Alert
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting Android 6.0 or above ?

Comment: Yep! Android 6.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps targeting Android 6.0 and above need to handle the run-time permission.
Refer the Android documentation [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
I think, this might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare receiver on your manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.example.EventBroadcaster"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```